# How is it possible that an LC Oscillator create a sine wave?

Tags: capacitor, oscillator, inductor, passive-networks

I have a question, for example look at this circuit:

[image]

1)How is it possible if this circuit can oscillate, for example taking on the capacitor full charged, and the inductor full discharged, the capacitor, since there isn't a resistance is shorted, so how can it create a sinesuoidal wave?

2)How is is possible, taking on the capacitor full charged, and without a resistance, that this circuit swinging will create a sinusoidal wave, and not for example an exponential signal [In voltage], like for example in an RC circuit, like that:
[image]

Comment: It starts with energy stored in the capacitor. With your proposal, that energy goes away somewhere. Where did it go?

Comment: If you were to look at the set of coupled differential equations describing this system, namely \$I = C\, dV/dt\$ and \$V = -L\, dI/dT\$ (with a sign flipped to respect KCL/KVL), would you agree that the equations have a family of solutions that is composed of sine waves?

Comment: Time is not frequency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) ... the capacitor, since there isn't a resistance is shorted, so how can it create a sinesuoidal wave?

The inductor might have a very low resistance (or zero in the ideal case) so it presents a short-circut for DC but not for AC. The thing is that it's not DC - the current is changing.

> 2) How is is possible, taking on the capacitor full charged, and without a resistance, that this circuit swinging will create a sinusoidal wave, ...

The energy is sloshing back and forth between the capacitor and the inductor.

Answer (score 1):

You know the current in the capacitor must be the same as the current in the inductor. Ground the bottom node, for a simple reference point. Then the current ***into*** the capacitor from the top mode (whose voltage is \$V\$) is \$I_\text{C}=C\cdot\frac{\text{d} \,V}{\text{d}\,t}\$. The current ***into*** of the inductor is \$I_\text{L}=\frac{1}{L}\int \:V\:\text{d}\,t\$. But we must reverse the sign of one or the other before saying they are equal: \$C\cdot\frac{\text{d} \,V}{\text{d}\,t}=\frac{-1}{L}\int \:V\:\text{d}\,t\$. Take the derivative of both sides with respect to time to get: \$C\cdot\frac{\text{d}^2 \,V}{\text{d}\,t^2}=\frac{-V}{L}\$ or else just \$\frac{\text{d}^2 \,V}{\text{d}\,t^2}=\frac{-V}{L\,C}\$. That's a second-order, linear, ordinary diff-eq and the general solution is:

$$\begin{align*}V_t&=C_1\cdot \operatorname{cos}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{L\,C}}\right)+C_2\cdot \operatorname{sin}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{L\,C}}\right)\\\\&=\sqrt{C_1^{\,2}+C_2^{\,2}}\:\cdot\operatorname{sin}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{L\,C}}+\operatorname{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{C_1}{C_2}\right)\right)\\\\&=\sqrt{C_1^{\,2}+C_2^{\,2}}\:\cdot\operatorname{sin}\left(\omega\,t+\phi\right)\text{, where }\omega=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L\,C}}\text{ and }\phi=\operatorname{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{C_1}{C_2}\right)\end{align*}$$

\$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ are constants of integration.

Note the sine function?